# Is specific impulse and thrust maximum in vacuum or for exit pressure equals atmospheric pressure?

Tags: thrust, nozzle

According to the thrust formulation of a rocket one can show, that maximum thrust is not delivered for p<sub>ambient</sub>= 0  but for p<sub>ambient</sub>=p<sub>nozzle_exit</sub>  since then the momentum term is maximized.

But then I read that the specific impulse is maximum for a nozzle for vacuum, how does this match?

Specific Impulse = Thrust / (massflow * g<sub>0</sub> )

So if thrust is maximized for p<sub>ambient</sub>=p<sub>nozzle_exit</sub> then I<sub>sp_max</sub> should not be in vacuum?

Comment: A nozzle may be optimized for a certain ambient pressure. Optimization for a vacuum is not possible, the nozzle length would be infinite.

Answer (score 3):

**Both Thrust and Isp are maximized in a vacuum**

This is plainly true when you see the thrust equation:

$$ F = \dot{m}v_e + A_e(Pe-Pa) $$

For a given rocket, say the Sea-level optimized Merlin engine, the massflow ($\dot{m}$) is fixed by the engine throttling and pump pressure; the exit velocity ($V_e$) is fixed by the nozzle expansion and the combustion temp. Exit area ($A_e$) is not changing unless some funky business is afoot.

The only variable that we can play with for the Merlin engine at fixed throttle etc. is the ambient pressure ($P_a$), and since all the other variables are fixed, it is clear that thrust is maximized when ambient pressure is zero.

Any under expanded nozzle is producing more thrust than it’s “optimal condition”.  It is just that **at that altitude/back pressure the thrust could be increased even more by extending the nozzle** but it is already performing better than at Pa=Pe=e.g. sea level pressure.

**A rocket *design* is optimized by equating Pe and Pa, but a rocket *performance* is always improved by reducing back pressure**

Comment: Thank you For your answer A McKelvy. How does this match to the answer here: 

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/306140/why-the-exhaust-pressure-should-be-equal-to-ambient-pressure

" An underexpanded nozzle (one in which pe>pa ) will have a significantly reduced exhaust velocity compared to a perfectly expanded nozzle. The slight gain in thrust due to the positive (pe−pa)A
 term does not offset the significant loss in thrust due to the suboptimal value of the m˙ve
 term."

So as far as I understand the thrust is maximized for p_exit = p_ambient

Comment: @Kevin that answer is uninformed.  Exit velocity is independent of over vs under expansion.  It is basically a function of nozzle expansion ratio and chamber temp.  Critically NOT dependent on pressure.  That answer gets the importance of Ve right, it is why we want to match Pe and Pa, but it is only by changing the nozzle design that we can play with Ve.

Comment: Sorry A McKelvy but I do not get the point. When I have a look at this youtube explanation it tells me also that thrust is maximum for pe=pa       

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3ylH8onOlw

Comment: We are discussing on-design and off-design conditions.  If you are designing a rocket for a particular altitude, its thrust at that altitude will be max when Pe=Pa (on-design).  If you then take that engine youve designed and move it a higher altitude, it will provide more thrust.  Once the engine is made, all the terms in the thrust equation freeze EXCEPT Pa.

Comment: Thank you . that helped!

Comment: Or in short, "atmospheric pressure" in vacuum is zero. That means infinitely big nozzle would be "optimal" - except for practical considerations, like its mass and size you have to haul through the atmosphere, plus diminishing returns as you approach zero pressure.

Comment: @SF. If the nozzle was infinitely long you wouldn't even have to launch it. Just climb it.